# storing argv[1] to a char or int in C

Tags: c, string, argv, atoi

So, I'm not sure whether I should try to convert argv[1] to an int or if I can leave it as a char.  But I'm having difficulties getting argv to behave the way I want it to.

My terminal input will look like this:

```
./a.out a
```

where argv[1] can either be an 'a' or a 'd'.

The Problem:  when trying to pass it through an if statement such as:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *letter;
  letter=argv[1];

  printf(" %s  %s ", argv[1], letter); //THIS prints correctly

//However, even when the input IS 'a', it will still print this:

  if(letter != "a" || letter != "d") 
      printf("Input letter not 'a' or 'd'\n");
  else{//More stuff//}    
}
```

I get all kinds of errors when I attempt to fix it myself. I saw a few threads explaining argv[1][0] and using atoi, but after playing around with it, I could not get it to print out.

Comment: Are you using C or C++?  They are different languages, with different answers.  Please don't tag both, unless the question is specifically about the differences.

Comment: sorry about that, it's just in C.  I removed the tag, thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Use `strcmp` to compare strings. Do not compare pointers the way you do.

Comment: `argv[1]` is a pointer to a string. `"a"` is a *string literal*. `letter` is a pointer to a string. You cannot compare *strings* with `==` or `!=`.

Comment: `argv[1]` is a `char*`. Specifically, either a `NULL` pointer or a pointer to the first character of the first argument. Since it's something you don't control, you can't just assume it's either a or d.

Comment: `if(letter != "a" || letter != "d")` --> `if(strcmp(letter, "a") && strcmp(letter, "d"))`

Comment: BTW, your condition(in case it was working) will be true always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no sense to compare the value of the pointer `argv[1]` with the addresses of the first characters of the string literals `"a"` and `"d"`.

Just write

```
#include <string.h>

//...

if( letter == NULL || ( strcmp( letter, "a" ) != 0  && strcmp( letter, "d" ) != 0 ) ) 
      printf("Input letter not 'a' or 'd'\n");
```